# Firebase observer architecture

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

Okay, so I'm trying to build an iOS app that relies on Firebase (To work with its android version)

I started with creating a repository for each actor in my app and a general repository to manage them all

[image]

Each repository manages the observers of this actor. An example:

Inside the PagesRepository, this is a function that retrieves all the pages from Firebase and returns it inside a completionHandler:

```
//MARK: Gets the whole pages list
func getPagesList(completionHandler: @escaping (_ pages: [Page]?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {

    func displayError(error: String) {
        print(error)
        completionHandler(nil, self.getErrorFromString(error))
    }

    pagesRef.observe(DataEventType.value) { pagesSnapshot in

        guard pagesSnapshot.exists() else {
            displayError(error: "Pages snapshot doesn't exist")
            return
        }

        var pagesList = [Page]()
        for pageSnapshot in pagesSnapshot.children {
            pagesList.append(Page(snapshot: pageSnapshot as! DataSnapshot))
        }
        completionHandler(pagesList, nil)
    }
}
```

And then I call it from the ViewController like this:

```
repository.getPagesList { (pages, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }

        //Do processing
    }
```

I know this may be a lot to take in, but **my problem is that every time I call the function, it creates a new observer but doesn't cancel the old one... So, the completionHandler is called multiple times with different values**

How should I manage this problem?
(Sorry for being complicated and a little unclear, I'm just really lost)

Comment: Don't do this - it won't work and will be really hard to maintain. Firebase is asynchronous and you should work with the snapshot data *within the closure* (populating the array, then updating the UI). Calling Firebase observe methods expecting them to return data in that fashion will make your UI weird. It's unclear why getPagesList is called over and over - that's not generally how Firebase works; you should let Firebase do the heavy lifting and notify you when new data has been added, changed or removed. Also, the pages array appears to be a class var (?) so there's no reason to pass it.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information to really answer this properly; while there is an answer it may not the the correct one for this use case. Why are you calling getPagesList repeatedly? Why are you using a completion handler instead of just putting the code within the closure? What are you doing with the pagesList array - is it a tableView datasource or something else? Why are you including a function that print's an error when the error could just be printed directly?

Comment: @Jay I can actually put it directly, but I want to divide the data code from the UI code. It’s just an architecture decision

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you only want to observe the value once so I would use this instead:

```
func getPagesList(completionHandler: @escaping (_ pages: [Page]?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {

    func displayError(error: String) {
        print(error)
        completionHandler(nil, self.getErrorFromString(error))
    }

    pagesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (pagesSnapshot) in
      var pagesList = [Page]()

      for pageSnapshot in pagesSnapshot.children {
          pagesList.append(Page(snapshot: pageSnapshot as! DataSnapshot))
      }

      completionHandler(pagesList, nil)

      }) { (error) in
        // Display error
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I actually want to keep my UI up to date... The problem is that I have to call the getPages function more than once. And that results in several observers existing and the completionHandler being called more than once

Comment: Are you calling this function in multiple controllers? Because you can create the observer in viewWillAppear and ref.removeAllObservers() in viewWillDisappear()